# how to return byte array , uint value from c# dll, dll called by c++/cli

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I am writing a c# DLL which will calculate and produce:-

```
-byte array [byte array]
-unit       [2 byte error code]
-bool       [true/false for success and failure]
```

this function will called by C++/CLI project. A function can return only one value but i need these 3 values after c# function execute.

what will be the function prototype in C# and how it called by C++/CLI code.

thanks in advance

Comment: Just write a method that returns a byte[].  It is `array<Byte>^` in C++/CLI.  "Error codes" should be exceptions.

Comment: @HansPassant: That really depends on whether the failure is expected or not.  E.g. when parsing foreign data input, invalid input is not really exceptional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `out` modifier.

```
void MyMethod(out byte[] ba, out short code, out bool success)
{
    ...
}
```

As say [here](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/813926-calling-managed-method-out-parameter-c), the call will be:

```
array<System::Byte>^ ba;
Int16 code;
bool success;
MyClass::MyMethod(ba, code, success);
```

I just tested it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Worth mentioning the TryXXX pattern (`TryParse`, `Dictionary<Key,Value>::TryGetValue` etc) that does this, except that the bool success becomes the return value.

Comment: i used ref and it's working good.                                 public bool READ_KEY(ref uint errorcode, ref byte[] temp, ref uint array_length)

Answer (score 3):

Try to return structure or class of this elements.

Answer (score 0):

As Hans Passant said in the comments, errors should be exceptions, not part of the return value. If you're having problems with the syntax, here's what I would do:

In C#:

```
public class CSharpClass
{
    public static byte[] Foo()
    {
        // ...
        if (some error condition)
        {
            throw new SomeException(...); 
            // If you really want, write your own exception class
            // and have the error code be a property there.
        }

        byte[] result = new byte[1024];
        return result;
    }
}
```

In C++/CLI:

```
public ref class CppCLIClass
{
public:
    static void Bar()
    {
        try
        {
            array<Byte>^ fooResult = CSharpClass::Foo();
            // Success, no error occurred.
        }
        catch (SomeException^ e)
        {
            // An error occurred.
        }
    }
}
```